# Short to jump from selection to selection in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, emmet

I want to use ctrl+d / cmd+d to make multiple selections, but then in the case when I have to increment a number (for example 1.jpg , 2.jpg, 3.jpg) I want to jump easily from selection to selection... (or use some Emmet / Sublime magic to do the incrementing automatically?)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package called [`Insert Nums`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Insert%20Nums), that does exactly that and much more. I'd recommend reading [the docs at Github](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/InsertNums) for more information about the package.

Comment: This does exactly what I want, thanks. I was also looking for a shortcut that would allow me to manually jump from selection to selection, in case I am not increasing a number but inserting custom text.

Comment: There might be a feature like that in the MultiEditUtils (https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/MultiEditUtils) package.